# Век или века

Tags: согласование

"Первая половина 12 - 14 век (в.)" или "первая половина 12 - 14 века (вв.)"?

Comment: Тогда, скорее, правильно написать "первая половина XII - начало XIV веков" - без сокращений. И века лучше обозначать римскими цифрами.

Comment: Первая половина 12-14 веков! Правильно. Что тут непонятного? Элементарно: первая половина трех веков (а не трех века). А римские или арабские цифры - значения не имеет.

Comment: Крайне некорректный вопрос. Контекста маловато

Comment: Надо бы править, но неуважительны к возрасту Вопроса и Комментаторам исправления будут. А они были б уместны от того, что арабские цифры не годится в счислении лет употреблять. Автору привет от грамматики русской. А вот -/— поменяю.

Answer (score 3):

*"Первая половина XII - XIV век".*
Или даже *"с первой половины XII (века) по XIV век".*
Иначе двусмысленность не устранить.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: "первая половина 12 - 14 веков (вв.)". Хотя по смыслу непонятно: что такое первая половина 12-14 веков? В смысле первая половина каждого из этих веков (12, 13, 14-го) или первая половина данного промежутка времени, то есть 12-й и первая половина 13-го века?
 Насчет римских цифр я согласна, но если речь идет о периоде с начала (первая половина) ХII до конца ХIV века, то следует писать "XII-XIV века", а если о второй половине, то "период со второй половины XII по XIV век".

Comment: Имеется ввиду период начиная с первой(второй, конца и т.п.)половины века и включая целый последующий век(а). В научной литературе в таких случаях пишут римские цифры через тире. Например:  конец X - XII в.? вв.? Не можем найти какой-либо нормативной ссылки для такого, довольно распространённого случая. Помогите, для нас очень важно!

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая Ваш комментарий - пояснение к ответу kukolka-bale..., замечу, что выражение "первая половина 12" в этом контексте крайне неудачно. Если в предполагемый период входит первая половина 12 века и вторая тоже, плюс ещё два века, то не проще ли будет сказать 12-14 века? 
Скорее всего, Вас интересует не первая, а вторая половина 12 века и ещё два века. В этом случае можно сказать так: "со второй половины 12 века и до конца 14-го (или до начала 15)..." или "вторая половина 12 века и 13-14 века" (если Вам нужен именительный падеж).

Comment: Отчасти я соглашусь, датировка довольнол необычна. Но вряд ли у нас есть основание считать что автор перепутал половины века. Видимо, здесь по задумке что-то типа "начало XII - конец XIV века", но по каким-то причинам автор не может дать более точную датировку начала и конца периода. Не зная, о чем ижет речь, сказать наверняка сложно. Пусть останется на совести автора.

Answer (score 1):

Понятно, что "первая половина" в данном контексте бессмыслица, уточняют дату начиная со второй четверти века, если событие было до **25 года и продолжалось весь век, то это ясно из отсутствия уточнений.

Теперь к сути вопроса. Запись: *кон X - XII вв.* - графическое сокращение фразы *С конца десятого по двенадцатый* **века** и читаться она должна именно так. В редких контекстах возможны конструкции *конец двенадцатого - четырнадцатый века*, но и там двусмысленностей не возникает из-за разных падежей числительных. При этом *в.* - это сокращение от век, а *вв.* - от векА.

Касательно римских и арабских цифр. Века пишут и римскими и арабскими цифрами, но в последнем случае будет необходимо добавлять буквенное наращение, *ХХ век*, но *20-й век*. В исторических трудах пишут почти исключительно римскими цифрам, в силу традиции, и чтобы век не сливался с датами-годами.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь, § 194. Два определения при одном существительном, подп. 6 п. 1:  В сочетаниях типа в конце XIX и начале XХ века: однородными членами здесь являются существительные начало и конец, а не порядковые числительные. То же самое в выражениях типа от Северного до Южного полюса: между прилагательными-названиями нет сочинительной связи. Источник: http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xliv.html#sect195

Comment: Так как правильно - и почему? И как вы вообще понимаете смысл разбираемой конструкции? Здесь принято давать развернутый ответ а не разрозненные цитаты.